# Increased system CPU time in non-threaded regions of OpenMP code

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

I am experiencing a very peculiar issue. I am parallelizing parts of a very large code (about 600MB of source code) using OpenMP, but I'm not getting the speedups I expected. I profiled many parts of the code using `omp_get_wtime()` to get reliable estimates, and I discovered the following: the OpenMP parts of my code do have better `wall times` when I use more threads, however when I turn the threads on the program has increased `system cpu time` usage in parts of the code where there are no `omp pragmas` at all (e.g., time spent in IPOPT). I used `grep` for `pragma` to make sure. Just to clarify, I know for sure from my profiling and code structure that the threaded parts and the parts where I get the slowdowns run in completely different times.

My code consists of two main parts. The first is the base code (about 25MB of code), which I compile using `-fopenmp`, and the second is third-party code (the remaining 575MB) which is not compiled with the OpenMP flag.

Can anyone think of a reason why something like this could be happening? I can't fathom it being resource contention since the slowdowns are in the non-threaded parts of the code.

I am running my code on a 4-core (2 physical cores) Intel-i7 4600U compiled using `clang++-3.8` in Ubuntu 14.04, with `-O3` optimizations.

Any ideas would be great!

Comment: Do the supposedly non-OpenMP parts of your application get shorter wall times when you enable threads? How do you control the number of threads? `OMP_NUM_THREADS`? IPOPT at least does something with `OMP_NUM_THREADS`. How is IPOPT built? Do you use MKL? Any library use use could use OpenMP or `OMP_NUM_THREADS`. Without a [mcve], this is all just guessing.

Comment: I would recommend not to spend much time on "printf-style"-performance analysis, but use a tool such as [Score-P](http://score-p.org/) & [Vampir](http://vampir.eu) to see how the "parallel"/"sequential" executions actually differ. If built properly*, it will tell you which part of your code will use threads. *: That may be difficult for complex applications.

Comment: @Zulan Yes, I use `omp_set_num_threads`. The non OpenMP parts get longer wall times when I set more than one thread, this is what baffles me. I just greped it again, there is no `num_thread` or `pragma` string in IPOPT or any of the code which is lagging. I'm not using MKL.Sorry for not providing an example, but I just can't narrow it down to a specific (small) part of the code. The slowdowns just accumulate over time. Thanks for your time anyway!

Comment: Are you compiling **all** involved libraries yourself from source? I'm afraid in the current form it is impossible to answer the question.

Comment: Hmmm yes, apart from the system libraries. I'm not very experienced with multithreading so I thought it might be some context switching, but I'm not sure if that's applicable in the non-threaded parts of the code. Sorry for making this so vague.!